# .htaccess wrong redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I force http to https redirection in my .htaccess and it works just fine. But I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ rule, not to redirect http://example.com/robots.txt anywhere and just serve the robots.txt file.

The problem is, it does not work and http://example.com/robots.txt gets somehow redirected to http://example.com/index.php url.

My .htaccess is as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you make any excemptions? Whats the problem in serving `robots.txt` over HTTPS as well?

Comment: @NicoHaase when you keep original robots.txt under the http protocol, robots that have url to this old robots.txt will realize faster that links w/o https are now redirected to https. It's kind of good practice, thought. However, can't say how important it is in reality.

Comment: "It's kind of good practice" sounds strange. Do you have any source for that? Redirecting everything, everything to HTTPS should be "fast" as well

Comment: @NicoHaase As I understand it (not being SEO expert), if we keep old HTTP robots.txt with old HTTP links, we say explicitly to search engines that the old links are redirected with 301 (all the links from old robots.txt get redirected). If we offer only new HTTPS robots.txt with new HTTPS links, it's not explicitly stated on our side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It redirects because last rule change `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php`. You should be using `THE_REQUEST` variable in first rule as that doesn't get overwritten after application of rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Also make sure to test this change in a new browser or test it after completely clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Ty! I changed the line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ to  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/robots\.txt [NC] but non HTTPS http://example.com/robots.txt redirects to HTTPS version now - https://example.com/robots.txt. I did not change last rows of the htaccess as I got an error.

Comment: So the problem now is, that http request for robots.txt get still redirected to https.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: I tried. When I request non-https robots.txt, I get "Initiator: Other" and  Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache). Redirection is to https version of robots.txt url.

Comment: That means you have not disabled caching in dev tool. There is a checkbox to disable caching

Comment: I see, I just clear the cache after every fresh upload of a new version of .htaccess.

Comment: I just checked the apache version. It's quite old: Apache/2.2.22 (FreeBSD). Server built:   Jul 23 2012 23:51:38

Comment: I have updated rules but under no condition this rule will redirect `/robots.txt`. You can even rename this .htaccess and check `example.com/robots.txt`

Comment: This answer solved the original question, when HTTP example.com/robots.txt was getting redirected to HTTP example.com/index.php url. I replaced %{REQUEST_URI} with %{THE_REQUEST}. But there is still a problem mentione here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502465/htaccess-is-ignoring-rewritecond