# .htaccess is ignoring RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/robots.txt [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Main part is the HTTPS redirect.  I do not want to redirect robots.txt to https, but the

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/robots.txt [NC]`

is always ignored and robots.txt is also redirected to https.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition will always return false:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/robots.txt [NC]
```

It is because of start anchor `^` before `/` since an example value of `THE_REQUEST` is:

```
GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1
```

So accordingly change your condition to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+robots\.txt\s [NC]
```

and retest in a new browser.